# How to use checkbox under description of any webform field?

Tags: 6, webforms, theming, forms

I am using webform module where I have a text field named Mobile Phone Number.

I wanted to use checkbox under the text field as shown below:
[image]

The content can be written in the description of that text field. But how do I use the checkbox as I shown above.

*Note: I tried to enter the html form tags in the description but didn't help.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a select field form component with label name as 'agree' and tick marked multiple so that checkbox will appear and provided a *single key|value pair* as shown below. 
 [image]

*Keep this select component under the mobile phone number component. It will appear exactly next to mobile phone number component then just hide the label, make proper alignments using **css**.*

Answer (score 2):

You will create a check box component fields below mobile phone number fields after "yes|I am providing my express..." in **OPTIONS** . 
   Create Check box -> Options -> "yes|I am providing my express..."
     [image]
and align with CSS code

Comment: Where is options box in webform's text field?

Comment: rewrite my answer now please check

Comment: This is available with the webform's select field not with the textfield. I want it in the textfield's desciption so that it will be available just under my text box. If you mean using a separate checkbox then align it with css code then it might work but not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) hook to alter the form (in template.php):

```
function MY_THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  if($form_id == 'MY_WEBFORM_FORM_ID' /* you can find formid with dpm function from Devel module or you can also use PHP's debugging functions, e.g. dpm($form_id) */) {
    $form['my_checkbox'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => 'Your Long Description',
      '#weight' => 50, /* this value must be something like `phone number field's weight + 1` */
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

and flush the cache..

Comment: Is there any other easy way to do this without using hook_form_alter since this is just for one particular case.

Comment: @NewDrupalUser Altering th form not such a bad way, even this is a single case. In other hand, by hooking into the form you can get other advantages such as adding custom submit handler, validation handler and so on.. (likely you will need them..)